# A non-numeric value encountered in PHP - ecommerce site

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, mamp

I am trying to use php sessions to store a variable however it doesn't want to play ball.

I get the error : Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /Users/mac/Briefcase/Web Design/Testing/Udemy/ecommerce/cart.php on line 119

Interestingly, the error displays twice.

I'm running MAMP 4.2.1 and php 7.1.8

I have declared a session_start as the first thing in the document, any idea what is going on? Thanks :)

Full code in a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/AVtq97uG

```
    <td><input type="text" size="6" name="qty" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['qty']; ?>"/></td>
    <?php
     if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){
      $qty = $_POST['qty'];
      $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty'";
      $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);

      $_SESSION['qty'] = $qty;
      $total = $total * $qty;


     }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiplies values that are not numbers.

```
$total = $total * $qty;
```

Ex:

```
echo 12 * "test" ; // PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered
echo 12 * "12" ; // Works : 144
```

Here, `$qty` come from user input, and could not be a number.

You have to check this value before and not do operation if the value is not a number.

You could check using [`is_numeric()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) :

```
if (isset($_POST['update_cart']) && 
    isset($_POST['qty']) && 
    is_numeric($_POST['qty'])) 
{
   // do stuff
} else {
   // error fallback 
}
```